# Alignment of Hebrew Vowel points in Android

Tags: android, text, hebrew

I want to display Hebrew text with vowel points (nikkud) using the Canvas.drawText interface. The vowel points come out misaligned, as in the following image taken using a Motorola Defy+ device:

[image: Misaligned vowels]

The hiriq is between the resh and the yod, the holam between the vav and nun.
I have added the rtl code (\u200F) to the string at both ends, no joy.
I know that there are applications that have solved this problem, such as the Smart Siddur.  Is there a difference between text-based applications and graphics based?  I would think that the same engine renders the text in both cases. I suppose I could split up the string and place the vowels separately, but that seems pretty painful and not extensible.
TIA for any clues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the following works.  I still don't understand why I had to implement it, but this does work...

```
 package com.lomda.ong2;

import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.FontMetricsInt;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.graphics.Paint.Align;
import android.graphics.Paint.FontMetrics;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.Log;

// render Hebrew strings with diacritic marks
// 
public class HebRender {

Paint paint;
HashMap<String, Integer> spaces;
String charString;
String prevChar = "";
final String TAG = "HebRender";

public HebRender(Context svContext){
    paint = new Paint(); 
    Typeface t =  Typeface.createFromAsset(svContext.getAssets(),"fonts/SimpleCLM-Bold.ttf");
    //Typeface t =  Typeface.createFromAsset(svContext.getAssets(),"fonts/gisha.ttf");
    paint.setTypeface(t);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL); 
    paint.setTextSize(48); 
    paint.setAntiAlias(true); 
    paint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD); 
    paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
}

public void drawText(   Canvas canvas, String word, Point locate, int color) {
    Rect bounds = new Rect();
    Rect prevBounds = new Rect(0,0,0,0);
    paint.getTextBounds(word, 0, word.length(), bounds);
    paint.setColor(color);
    int wordWidth = bounds.width();
    // move to right edge (parameter is center)
    locate.x += wordWidth/2;
    // initialize bounds of individual characters
    bounds = new Rect(0,0,0,0);
    // for each character
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        // locate and write letter
        char c = word.charAt(i);
        charString = String.valueOf(c); 
        if (c >= 1488 && c <=1514) {// is in consonant range
            paint.getTextBounds(charString, 0, charString.length(), bounds); // get current char dimensions
            if (!prevChar.equals("")) {
                int moveOver = bounds.width()/2 + prevBounds.width()/2 + (int) paint.getTextSize()/10;
                locate.x -= moveOver;
            }
            Log.d(TAG, String.format("Char: %s, Prev char width: %d, char width: %d", charString, prevBounds.width(), bounds.width()));
            canvas.drawText(charString, locate.x, locate.y, paint);
            prevChar = charString;
            prevBounds.set(bounds); // save previous dimensions
        } else {// for each diacritic locate and write
            canvas.drawText(charString, locate.x + getOffset(c, bounds.width()), locate.y, paint);
        }

    }
}

// some diacritic marks need to be moved 
private int getOffset(char c, int charWidth) {
    int offset = 0;
    switch (c){
    case 0x05C1:  // shin dot
        offset = charWidth/2;
        break;
    case 0x05C2:  // sin dot
        offset = -charWidth/2;
        break;
    case 0x05BC:  // dagesh
        offset = findDagesh(c, charWidth);
        break;
    case 0x05B9: // holam
        offset = -(3*charWidth/5);
        break;
    }
    return offset;
}

// move dagesh around for certain characters
private int findDagesh(char c, int charWidth) {
    int offset = 0;
    if (prevChar.equals("ג")) {
        offset = Math.min(2, -charWidth/3);
    } else if (prevChar.equals("ו") ||prevChar.equals("ז") || prevChar.equals("י")){
        offset = Math.min(7, -7*charWidth/10);
    } else if (prevChar.equals("ע") || prevChar.equals("ש") ) {
        offset = Math.max(1, charWidth/3);
    } else if (prevChar.equals("פ")){
        offset = Math.max(2, charWidth/3);
    }
    return offset;
}
```

}

Comment: Hi @Aharonmanne. I'm working on a Sidor app and I'm having an issue with the Nikud. Is there a better (less CPU intensive) nowadays?

Answer (score 0):

This could be an issue with the font you are using, as you could reproduce the same problem on your desktop computer as well. Although Android itself has Hebrew glyphs these days, there are much difference between vendors, so even if it will work well on one device it doesn't most work well on every other device.

My suggestion is to workaround this by supplying your own font. You can for example use the fonts from the [Culmus Project](http://culmus.sf.net) which are free and most of them known to support Hebrew vowel points well enough.

Comment: I tried both the Gisha font and the Simple font from Culmus. No joy with either.

Comment: I tried all possible combinations of adding \u200F at both ends of the string.  In combination and separately, I tried paint.setTextAlign(Align.RIGHT/Align.LEFT/Align.Center).  None of these parameters seemed to have any effect.<br> At this point I am trying to implement a manual solution, iterating over each codepoint separately.  I can't believe that this hasn't been solved.